# Optional.orElse(null) is marked with org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

Tags: java, sonarqube

How is `Optional.orElse(null)` marked with `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`

The javadoc of `orElse` explicitly states that null is allowed

```
     * @param other the value to be returned, if no value is present.
     *        May be {@code null}.
```

But my code flags a "bug" in SonarQube.

```
        return users.findById(userID)
            .flatMap(user -> students.findByUser(user))
            .map(GetAllStudentsSvc::mapToStudent)
            .orElse(null);
```

Looking at the code it doesn't appear to be marked.  Looking at the IDE it also does not appear to be marked

[image]

Even annotating the code as `@Nullable` does not help.

[image]

Comment: What are the methods findById, findByUser and mapToStudent are returning?

Comment: `Optional` I'll update the title.

Comment: Okay, that is actually interesting.. I don't have an answer then

Comment: I’d wonder if any JDK class like `java.util.Optional` was using a jetbrains annotation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. I am pretty sure that when you annotate the method that returns what you showed with @NotNull, then IDE will flag that your code might evaluate to null.

Comment: I didn't add any annotations, but adding `nullable` does not help.  I updated the OP

Comment: You are using a linter called `SonarLint`, it might be something to do with their lint rules

Comment: this is for SonarQube which SonarLint does the same thing.  I tagged this as Sonarqube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is clear that `null` is perfectly fine here, so I's suggest to suppress it. This worked for me:

`@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2637")`